# How do I define a list/vector of functions in R?

Tags: r, list, function

I have a function which takes another function as an input variable, eg.

```
WrapperFunction <- function(x, BaseFunction){
   y <- cor(x)
   BaseFunction(y)
}
```

Now I want to input various BaseFunctions into this WrapperFunction, to produce a vector of outputs, but how do I define  a list of functions so that instead of plugging in each function by hand, I can automate the process with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:n){
   output[i] <- WrapperFunction(x, FunctionList[i])
}
```

I've tried defining

```
FunctionList <- list()

FunctionList[1] = Function1 , etc....
```

, which didn't work.

Nor did defining

```
FunctionList <- c("Function1", "Function2", ...)
```

Comment: What kinds of `x` values and `BaseFunction` functions do you plan to pass to `WrapperFunction`? You can construct a list then use `lapply(funlist, WrapperFunction, x = whateverXis)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a list of functions, you can do something like:

```
myFuns <- list(mean, sd)
```

And then you can `lapply` over this list, or use the `for` loop as you wanted. If you use the `for` loop make sure that you use the `[[` syntax, because this makes sure that you are retrieving the function and not a length one list:

```
for (i in 1:n){
    output[i] <- WrapperFunction(x, myFuns[[i]])
}
```

*or*

```
lapply(myFuns, WrapperFunction, x = x)
```

Comment: Thanks. This method was what I originally tried (with the for loop), but I think I must have missed out the double square brackets in the for loop line. This time it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're using for your `x` value, I presume it's a matrix.  You can put some functions into a list then use `lapply`.

For example

```
m <- matrix(1:6, 2)
lst <- list(cov, diff)
lapply(lst, WrapperFunction, x = m)
#[[1]]
#              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
#[1,]  1.848893e-32 -6.162976e-33 -6.162976e-33
#[2,] -6.162976e-33  1.848893e-32 -6.162976e-33
#[3,] -6.162976e-33 -6.162976e-33  1.848893e-32
#
#[[2]]
#              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
#[1,] -2.220446e-16  2.220446e-16 0.000000e+00
#[2,]  0.000000e+00 -2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16
```

Also, as suggested by @nrussell, you can vectorize the `BaseFunction` argument, which is essentially the same as doing the above.

```
vWF <- Vectorize(WrapperFunction, vectorize.args = "BaseFunction")
vWF(m, lst)
```

This produces the same result as shown above.

Comment: Also `vWF <- Vectorize(WrapperFunction,vectorize.args="BaseFunction")` (which I think essentially just uses `lapply` when a single parameter is being vectorized).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way, Hope this answers your question ...

```
  ## Function 1
  fun1 <-function(a)
  {
    a = a+a
    return(a)
  }

  ## Function 2
  fun2 <- function(a)
  {
    a = a*a
    return(a)
  }

  ## Function 3
  fun3 <- function(a)
  {
  a = a^a
  return(a)
  }

  ## Vector of function names
  funlist <- c("fun1","fun2","fun3")

  ## Main Wrapper fnction
  mainfun <- function(x,funlist)
  {
    y = cor(x[,1],x[,2])

    res=NULL
    for(i in 1:length(funlist))
    {
      k <- eval(parse(text=paste(funlist[i],"(a=",y,")",sep="")),env=.GlobalEnv)
      res <- c(res,k)
    }

    return(c(y,res))
  }

  #############

  x=cbind(c(1:100),c(101:200))
  mainfun(x,funlist)

 [1] 1 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but let me add my two cents on while you're aggregating functions into a `list`, especially in the way to manipulate them for making bstract calls on your aggregated functions

let me retake the example below where we aggregate avg & st function

```
list_test <- list( avg=mean, std_dev=sd)
list_test
$avg
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x000001d32be1ef00>
<environment: namespace:base>

$std_dev
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
    na.rm = na.rm))
<bytecode: 0x000001d33bed49a0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

we can see when we call the list, it will send back the function definition. If you use the RStudio completion while manipulating `list_temp`, you'll get something like this

```
> v_test = rnorm(100)
> list_test$avg(v_test)
[1] 0.1973988
```

if you proceed without the `()`, you'll get the definition

```
list_test$avg
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x000001d32be1ef00>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

if you combine with the other way to manipulate r `list` objects, you'll get:

```
> list_test[[1]](v_test)
[1] 0.1973988
> list_test[["avg"]](v_test)
[1] 0.1973988
```

it's the kind of R subtleties I love and you can imagine what it can offer if you use a package like `purrr` :)